# Java, Decimal Format is expecting symbols?

Tags: java, decimalformat

here is my code

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
```

This is what I get out

```
C:\Users\HP\Desktop\Java\Projects>javac MathCalculations.java
MathCalculations.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
                ^
  symbol:   class DecimalFormat
  location: class MathCalculations
MathCalculations.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.##");
```

help please Ive been stuck on this for 3 and a half hours now.

Comment: Looks like you're missing an import.

Comment: Try to add this import and check `import java.text.DecimalFormat;`

Comment: import java.text.DecimalFormat to be precise. _Three and a half hours_?! Post your questions more quickly next time!

Comment: Take a look at the "For identifiers that should be class names" in the duplicate.